# Working on emulator, not on the device or another emulator. The set target is correct

Tags: runtime-error, android-logcat

here is the logCat file:

```
11-25 01:53:50.047: E/Trace(26246): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-25 01:53:50.057: D/ActivityThread(26246): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
11-25 01:53:50.057: D/ActivityThread(26246): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
11-25 01:53:50.057: D/ActivityThread(26246): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
11-25 01:53:50.117: D/AndroidRuntime(26246): Shutting down VM
11-25 01:53:50.117: W/dalvikvm(26246): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ecf378)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application my.app.cal.CalApplication: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4196)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:138)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:74)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at my.app.cal.CalApplication.readWeighingDetailFromDB(CalApplication.java:45)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at my.app.cal.CalApplication.onCreate(CalApplication.java:26)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4193)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am making an app that runs on the emulator, but now that i am trying to run it on mobile device on 4.1.2 platform, it gets Forced Closed messages immediately. 
I have kept Minimum Required SDK: API 11:Android 3.0(Honeycomb)
and Target SDK: API 18: Android 4.3.

Comment: I tried changing it to another emulator and its also getting forced closed. The LogCat works well with the old emulator. Both the emulator kept are API 18 and has 4.3 Platform. Can anyone explain me whats going on in the logcat here?

Comment: added here.. plz help now.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225916/my-app-is-working-on-emulator-not-on-device-log-cat-says-android-database-curs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something is wrong in the readWeightDeatilFromBD class in the onCreate Event !!