# My app is working on emulator, not on device. log cat says android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, sqlite, logcat

I am unable to find where on the database i have made a mistake. The app that i am making works on the emulator the emulator, but now that i am trying to run it on mobile device on 4.1.2 platform, it gets Forced Closed messages immediately. It was working fine one emulator as well as mobile before i started working on the database. I have kept Minimum Required SDK: API 11:Android 3.0(Honeycomb) and Target SDK: API 18: Android 4.3. I have added the activities on the Manifest file as well.

```
11-25 01:53:50.047: E/Trace(26246): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)    
11-25 01:53:50.057: D/ActivityThread(26246): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25    
11-25 01:53:50.057: D/ActivityThread(26246): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608    
11-25 01:53:50.057: D/ActivityThread(26246): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152    
11-25 01:53:50.117: D/AndroidRuntime(26246): Shutting down VM    
11-25 01:53:50.117: W/dalvikvm(26246): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ecf378)    
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application my.app.cal.CalApplication: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4196)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:138)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:74)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at my.app.cal.CalApplication.readWeighingDetailFromDB(CalApplication.java:45)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at my.app.cal.CalApplication.onCreate(CalApplication.java:26)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4193)
11-25 01:53:50.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26246):    ... 10 more
```

Here are my Data base files:
WeighingDetailDatabaseHelper.java:

```
package my.app.cal;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class WeighingDetailDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "MyWeighingDetail.SQLite";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static String WEIGHING_DETAIL_TABLE ="WeighingDetailTable";
    public static String RECORD_ID = "ID";
    public static String DATE ="Date";
    public static String WEIGHT = "Weight";


    public WeighingDetailDatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super (context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase weighingDetailDB) {

        String sqlStatement = "create table " + WEIGHING_DETAIL_TABLE
                + " (" 
                + RECORD_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"
                + DATE + " integer,"
                + WEIGHT + " float"
                + ");";

        Log.d("Weighing Database", sqlStatement);

        weighingDetailDB.execSQL(sqlStatement);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {


    }

}
```

WeighingDetail.java:

```
package my.app.cal;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;

public class WeighingDetail implements Comparable<WeighingDetail> {

    private long id;
    private float weight;
    private Date date;
    private float runningAverage;




    public WeighingDetail(float weight, Date date) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public WeighingDetail(long id, long dateEpoch, float weight) {
        this.id = id;
        setDateEpoch(dateEpoch);
        this.weight = weight;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public float getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(float weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public long getDateEpoch(){
        return date.getTime()/1000;

    }
    public void setDateEpoch(long seconds){
        date = new Date(seconds * 1000);
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


    public float getRunningAverage() {
        return runningAverage;
    }


    public void setRunningAverage(float runningAverage) {
        this.runningAverage = runningAverage;
    }
    public float sumofWeight() {
        return weight;  //Its just the weight itself, its used to calculate the running average weight later
    }

    public float calculateWeightAverage() {
        return weight;// Its the weight itself, used in averageEditText as well as for calculating total of the weights till now added
    }

    public boolean equals(Object that){
        WeighingDetail wd = (WeighingDetail) that;

        return this.date.equals(wd.date);
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(WeighingDetail that) {
        int difference;
        difference = this.date.compareTo(date);
        return difference;
    }

    public static void updateRunningAverage (ArrayList<WeighingDetail> allWeighingDetail) {

        int weeks = 1;
        float total = 0;

        Collections.sort(allWeighingDetail);

        if(allWeighingDetail.size() >0){
            for(WeighingDetail wd : allWeighingDetail){
                total +=wd.calculateWeightAverage();
                wd.setRunningAverage((float) total / (weeks));// first it was weeks = 3
                weeks++;
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result;
        //"ID:" + id + " " + 

        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
        result = df.format(date) + " " + weight  
                + String.format("%.1f", runningAverage);
        return result;
    }


}
```

a show history button shows the data base along with the running average, so its java file is ShowHistory.java that i have made.

```
package my.app.cal;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class HistoryActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<WeighingDetail> allWeighingDetail; //added an instance method to activity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history_layout);

        //get the data from the App
        CalApplication app = (CalApplication) getApplication();
        allWeighingDetail = app.getAllWeighingDetail();
        WeighingDetail.updateRunningAverage (allWeighingDetail);

        // View ------  Adapter    -----  Data

        setListAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<WeighingDetail>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        allWeighingDetail)



        );

    }
}
```

CalApplication.java

```
package my.app.cal;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import static my.app.cal.WeighingDetailDatabaseHelper.*;
public class CalApplication extends Application {

    private ArrayList<WeighingDetail> allWeighingDetail;
    private SQLiteDatabase weighingDetailDB;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        WeighingDetailDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new WeighingDetailDatabaseHelper(this);
        weighingDetailDB = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // TODO get the data out of the database

        readWeighingDetailFromDB ();

    }

    private void readWeighingDetailFromDB() {

        allWeighingDetail = new ArrayList<WeighingDetail>();

        Cursor weighingDetailCursor;

        weighingDetailCursor = weighingDetailDB.query(WEIGHING_DETAIL_TABLE,
                new String[]{RECORD_ID, DATE, WEIGHT},
                null, null, null, null,DATE);

        weighingDetailCursor.moveToFirst();
        WeighingDetail tempWD;

        if(weighingDetailCursor.isAfterLast()){
            do{
                long id = weighingDetailCursor.getLong(0);
                long dateEpoch = weighingDetailCursor.getLong(1);
                float weight = weighingDetailCursor.getFloat(2);

                tempWD = new WeighingDetail(id, dateEpoch, weight);

                allWeighingDetail.add(tempWD);

                Log.d("Weighing Database", tempWD.toString());
            }while(weighingDetailCursor.moveToNext());

        }
        weighingDetailCursor.close();

    }

    public void addWeighingDetail(WeighingDetail weighingDetail){

        assert weighingDetail != null;

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();//object that will put the data to the db
        cv.put(WeighingDetailDatabaseHelper.DATE, weighingDetail.getDateEpoch());//USE EPOCH
        cv.put(WeighingDetailDatabaseHelper.WEIGHT, weighingDetail.getWeight());

        Log.d("Weighing Database", "Before Inserting a record" + weighingDetail);

        long idPassedBack = weighingDetailDB.insert(WeighingDetailDatabaseHelper.WEIGHING_DETAIL_TABLE, null, cv);
        weighingDetail.setId(idPassedBack);

        Log.d("Weighing Database", "After Inserting a record" + weighingDetail);
        allWeighingDetail.add(weighingDetail);

    }

    public ArrayList<WeighingDetail> getAllWeighingDetail() {
        return allWeighingDetail;
    }

    private void setAllWeighingDetail(ArrayList<WeighingDetail> allWeighingDetail) {
        this.allWeighingDetail = allWeighingDetail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you here duplicate your question!. You should have edit your last question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180640/working-on-emulator-not-on-the-device-or-another-emulator-the-set-target-is-co

Comment: i have low reputation. i am unable to edit it more. so added it here.

Comment: The error is in the class `CalApplication` on method `readWeighingDetailFromDB` Line 45. Please paste that code.

Comment: instead of saying that, you could have looked into the problem. i am working hard on this app X(

Comment: Can you please share getAllWeighingDetail method?

Comment: Always use this condition when dealing with cursors:
`if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() )`

Check whether the cursor is null or not. If it not null, then move the cursor to the first record.

The cursor here is probably null (has no records).

Comment: thanks, both the answers helped! JoelFernandes & @Homosapiens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use this condition when dealing with cursors:

```
if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
//do operations with records
}
```

Check whether the cursor is null or not. If it not null, then move the cursor to the first record. The cursor here is probably null (has no records).

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value from moveToFirst(), before you try to read anything from the cursor. It looks as if no results are being returned.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
//do your effort
}
```